# CouchDB view documents with tag=foo or tag=bar

Tags: dictionary, couchdb

Given my following documents:

```
{
   _id: ###,
   type: "blogpost",
   title: "First blog post",
   tag: "tutorial"
}

{
   _id: ###,
   type: "blogpost",
   title: "Second blog post",
   tag: "report"
}

{
   _id: ###,
   type: "blogpost",
   title: "Third blog post",
   tag: "tutorial"
}

{
   _id: ###,
   type: "blogpost",
   title: "Fourth blog post",
   tag: "article"
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is: Find all blogposts which tag is article or report.

I already read in the documentation that I am able to perform a POST to a view or list, allowing for searching multiple keys. But this will always need cURL or something right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to specify article,report as variable in your HTTP call, then all you need is a view and a list

View: test_view

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.tag) {
    emit(doc.tag, doc);
  }
};
```

List: test_list

```
function(head, req) {
  start({
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/html"
    }
  });
  var row;
  var tags = req.query.tags;
  var tagArray = tags.split(',');
  while(row = getRow()) {
    if (tagArray.indexOf(row.key) != -1) {
      send(row.value.tag + ' : ' + row.value.title + '<br>');
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can get the list/html with
http://yourserver.com:5985/db/_design/test/_list/test_list/test_view?tags=article,report

Comment: Well that's exactly what i was looking for. My javascript knowledge is just nog great enough to figure that out for myself. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to create at least one view to make this work. I don't have a good idea of your needs so I'll just do a simple example without thought to it being the best way to implement what you want.

Visit Futon at http://yourserver.com:5984/_utils, and create a view in your database. You'll only need a map function to accomplish what you're asking for:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.tag && (doc.tag == "article" || doc.tag == "report")) {
        emit(doc.tag, doc);
    }
}
```

If you save your view and call it articles_or_reports, you can get the data from your view with this request:

```
http://yourserver.com:5984/db/_design/test/_view/articles_or_reports
```

Which will return

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"168ba21f7209994b69336dd8c30041f3","key":"article","value":{"_id":"168ba21f7209994b69336dd8c30041f3","_rev":"1-f033b30522d09c33cbd68332b89c95a7","type":"blogpost","title":"Fourth blog post","tag":"article"}},
{"id":"168ba21f7209994b69336dd8c3003139","key":"report","value":{"_id":"168ba21f7209994b69336dd8c3003139","_rev":"1-f7a473afc253972f7cfec62a335dcb23","type":"blogpost","title":"Second blog post","tag":"report"}}
]}
```

> But this will always need cURL or something right?

It depends on your application, but the only interface to CouchDB is through HTTP. There are libraries for many languages to bring your interactions to a higher level.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I indeed already created a view and list. However, I need the tags to be variables. So, something like this: http://yourserver.com:5985/db/_design/test/_view/blogs?key="article,report". Obviously this doesn't work but I need something like that without using post.